# Calling method with IOException

Tags: java, bluej

I cannot call this function that handles a text file.
I try to call it but an exception is thrown. I tried various approaches but nothing has worked so far.

```
public static void spracujSubor () throws IOException {
    File f = new File("test.txt");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    try {
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) { 
            String nazov = sc.next(); 
            String model = sc.next(); 
            double cena = sc.nextDouble(); 

            Auto rep = new Auto(nazov, model,cena); 
            aPozicovna.aAuto.add(rep);  
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.println(ioe);
    }
    sc.close(); 
}
```

Comment: What is the full text of the exception that you get? (DO NOT use `println(ioe)`.  Print the whole exception `ioe.printStackTrace()` or just throw the exception from `main`.)

Comment: also try changing IOException ioe to Exception e and change  System.err.println(ioe); to System.out.println(e.getMessage); .... Past the text of the error here

Comment: Changing `IOException` to `Exception` is a BAD idea.  It won't tell us / the OP anything new ... and it risks doing damage to the code (if the OP forgets to remove it afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we can't help you figure out what causes the `IOException` if you don't (at least) show us the exception's message.  The complete stacktrace would be ideal, but the message you help a lot.

There are multiple places where the `IOException` could be thrown, including:

1. In the `new Scanner(f)` if the file doesn't exist, isn't readable, has the wrong pathname, and a few other cases.
2. In the various calls on the `Scanner` object in the loop, depending on your file syntax.
3. In the `close()` call ... in theory.

Some of these are inside the try-catch.  Others are before or after it.  For the cases inside the try catch, you are catching the exception, printing a message, and then proceeding as if nothing happened.  That is bad.   Here is a better structure ... that *doesn't* squash the exceptions.

```
public static void spracujSubor () throws IOException {
    File f = new File("test.txt");
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(f)) {
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) { 
            String nazov = sc.next(); 
            String model = sc.next(); 
            double cena = sc.nextDouble(); 

            Auto rep = new Auto(nazov, model,cena); 
            aPozicovna.aAuto.add(rep);  
        }
    } 
}
```

Note that since the `Scanner` is an `Autocloseable`, it will be closed automatically when you exit the try-with-resources.